# cloud sql proxy as a service on windows 7

Tags: google-cloud-platform, windows-7, startup, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

Run "cloud_sql_proxy" as a service in "windows 7" operating system
I have the binary "cloud_sql_proxy" with which I can access the instance of the mysql server in the Google cloud platform, up there all right.
but I need to ensure that the executable provided by Google, is always running and so my application / client program does not lose the link to these services.

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I understand from your question, it seems you are attempting to ask “ How can I run cloud_sql_proxy_xXX.exe when I startup Windows 7 ?”. I can tell you that the proxy does not run as a service so you will have to execute it every time you boot up your machine. Luckily, running programs on startup for Windows 7 is relatively easier than later versions of Windows such as 8.X and above.

For Windows 7, You can follow the guided steps provided [here](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/add-programs-to-windows-7-startup-folder/). Essentially, you just have to put the .exe file you wish to run in your Startup folder under the Start menu. (I.e: Open Start menu > All Programs > Startup > Drag file in here)

This should execute  ”cloud_sql_proxy_xXX.exe” every-time you boot your Windows 7 local machine.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, i can solve the problem with something like that, adding the program to the windows register.
but best yet, i can run the program from my application at start up the same.
thanks anythin.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for GCP says literally:
"For the Windows operating system, run the proxy as a Windows Service. In general, the proxy should have the same uptime requirements as your application process."
so your answer is not acceptable.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more, please?